Opportunity Stage Change Flow Closing Opportunities Prematurely
Purpose of the Flow:
The flow is designed to automatically close certain opportunities when a new opportunity is created. Specifically, it should close any open opportunity titled "Undecided" by updating its stage to "Closed - Lost" when a new opportunity (with a title other than “Undecided”) is created for the same contact.
Entry Criteria:
The flow is triggered when an Opportunity record of the "S1" type is created or updated.
The "AccountId" on the Opportunity is checked to see if it differs from the AccountId on the related Primary Contact.
The flow does not use a Decision element because it relies on the "Type" field to filter records.
The Issue:
The flow works correctly when the “Undecided” opportunity already exists. If I create a new opportunity for the same contact, the flow properly updates the “Undecided” opportunity to "Closed - Lost." However, the issue arises when I create a brand new contact and then create a brand new “Undecided” opportunity. In this case, the flow prematurely closes the newly created “Undecided” opportunity, which is not the desired behavior since my users still need to work with these opportunities until a new one is created.
Additionally, I’ve noticed that when creating a brand new “Undecided” opportunity via data import, the flow does not close it. But when manually creating a new “Undecided” opportunity record, the flow triggers and closes the opportunity.
I have added some screenshots for clarity and omitted some titles for privacy. 
Entry Condition:
Condition Requirements: Custom Condition Logic is Met
Condition Logic: 1 AND NOT(2 OR 3)

Field: StageName
Operator: Does Not Equal
Value: Closed - Lost

Field: Name
Operator: Starts With
Value: Undecided 1

Field: Name
Operator: Starts With
Value: Undecided 2


Explanation: We have standardized Opportunity Names in my org, so for example a name would be "Undecided 1 - John Doe". This is what the logic is running off of.
Get Opps Lookup:
Object: Opportunity
Filter Opportunity Records
Condition Requirements: Custom Condition Logic is Met
Condition Logic: 1 AND ((2 AND 3) OR (4 AND 5)) AND 6

Field: Program_Plan__c
Operator: In
Value: ProgramPlanList

Field: Primary_Contact__c
Operator: Equals
Value: $Record > Primary Contact

Field: Primary_Contact__c
Operator: Is Null
Value: False

Field: Lead__c
Operator: Equals
Value: $Record > Lead

Field: Lead__c
Operator: Is Null
Value: False

Field: StageName
Operator: Does Not Equal
Value: Closed - Lost



Hi, thanks for your question and welcome to SFSE. Is your record triggered flow a before or after save, and are you ensuring that you are excluding the triggering record when you retrieve the related opportunities?

Hello! In my triggering element the trigger is set to "A Record is created or updated" and the 'when to run flow' is set to  "only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements". I don't see a specific option for Before or After Saves.
As far as opportunities, I'm currently not explicitly excluding the triggering record when retrieving related opportunities. The flow is set up to find all open opportunities for the same contact that have a specific name ("Undecided"), and if a new opportunity is created with a different name, it updates those to "Closed - Lost."

It sounds like the filters aren't specific enough to prevent the new 'Undecided' opportunities are being created. Are you checking the name of the Opportunities that are triggering your Flow as well as the type?

So for the entry condition and "Get Opps Lookup" I have written out the logic for both of them on my original post (having trouble uploading screen shots).
